# How to improve LSTM Multiclass text classification accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am relatively new to machine learning. I am building a supervised learning LSTM model. Word2Vec is used to build the word embedding. Accuracy is very poor 0.03 at the end of 100 epochs.

I have tried increasing LSTM neurons to 128, different activation functions (tanh, relu, and softmax). Still no luck.

Please suggest a way to improve the accuracy.

```
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 200
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 200

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_word,
                    output_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE,
                    input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                    embeddings_initializer = Constant(embedding_matrix),
                    trainable=False))

model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))

model.add(Dense(579, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
num_epochs = 100

history = model.fit(X_train, 
                    y_train, 
                    epochs=num_epochs, 
                    shuffle = True, 
                    batch_size=32,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test_categorical), 
                    verbose=2)
```

Model Summary:

- Total params: 145,097,931
- Trainable params: 48,931
- Non-trainable params: 145,049,000

Comment: You really have 579 classes? If so you need to use `softmax` in the last dense layer. You can wrap your LSTM with `Bidirectional`.

Comment: No improvement in accuracy after changing to softmax. I am supposed to get this work with LSTM and not Bi-LSTM

Comment: How did you load your word2vec embeddings, and whats is your final output is it a classification problem if so then softmax is what your looking for

Comment: Another question is how did you encode the text? Using the keras tokenizer?

Comment: yes, encoding was done using keras. word2vec embeddings were created after pre-processing the text.